# Override request-id http header produced by HttpClient in Angular2

Tags: angular, http-headers, httprequest, httpclient, azure-appservice

I have a simple method that sends an HTTP POST request to my backend API with a use of the HttpClient. The code snippet:

```
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
//other imports...

export class ApiService {
  private readonly apiUrl: Url;
  private readonly bearerToken: string;
  //other fields...

  public constructor(
    initialData: InitialDataService,
    private readonly httpClient: HttpClient
  ) {
    //some logic here
  }
    public sendCommand(command: ICommand): Observable<void> {
        const { __name, ...data } = command;
    
        return this.httpClient.post<void>(this.createCommandUrl(__name), data, {
          headers: {
            authorization: this.bearerToken,
            "request-id": createGuid()
          }
        });
      }

//...
}
```

When I run the code in the localhost Im able to see the generated Guid in the browser.
[image]

When I deploy the changes to Azure App service and I open the developer tools in the browser(tested in Firefox and Chrome), I'm able to see that the request-id is defined as an array of values rather than a single value produced by my method createGuid():

[image]

There is some additional value-added. Not sure why it behaves differently in the Cloud...

Is there a way to force the browser to use only the `request-id` provided by me and remove that extra one that appeared? I'd like to be able to do this for all types of HTTP calls. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using something like `applicationinsights-web` in the front end?
If so then this has a feature where it will add `request-id` and `request-context` headers to all XHR requests, unless you explicitly disable it. It might not be the Angular HTTP Client at all.

There are 4 ways of configuring this.

1. set `disableCorrelationHeaders` to `true` to switch it off for all requests
2. set `correlationHeaderExcludedDomains` to switch it off for requests to specific domains
3. set `correlationHeaderExcludePatterns` to fine tune which requests include\exlude the headers
4. set `enableCorsCorrelation` to `false` to switch it off for all CORS requests

Additional documentation is available here: https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-JS

And I believe the implementation of the code that checks these config values is here: https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-JS/blob/05a1f410589514a35e70d425b037888bb3d17d9f/shared/AppInsightsCommon/src/Util.ts#L735